# android jni c++ UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

JNI in my project ,but it does not work fun...  
**weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils.h**

```
#include &ltjni.h>
/* Header for class weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils */

#ifndef _Included_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils
#define _Included_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils
 * Method:    test
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**nativeapi.cpp**

```
#include &ltjni.h>
#include "weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils.h"
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    return env->NewStringUTF("This just a test for Android Studio NDK JNI developer!");
}
```

**The Log**

```
07-02 20:09:05.304 6306-6306/weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo, PID: 6306
                                                                            java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo.ImageUtils.test() (tried Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test and Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test__)
                                                                                at weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo.ImageUtils.test(Native Method)
                                                                                at weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**but I change .cpp to .c it work fun**  
**nativeapi.c**

```
#include &ltjni.h>
#include "weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils.h"
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"This just a test for Android Studio NDK JNI developer!");
}
```

**.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "weather.myapp.com.opencvdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "openCV"
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    sourceSets.main {
//        jni.srcDirs = []
//        jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
//    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

why I change .c++ to .c it works fun?and how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

***Explanation:***

your **test** function declaration is:

> extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test
>     (JNIEnv *, **jclass**);

and the function definition is:

> JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_weather_myapp_com_opencvdemo_ImageUtils_test
>           (JNIEnv *env, **jobject** obj) {...}

have different function signatures, so the function declaration is not applied to your **test** function, so with the **extern** keyword. As a consequence, the **test** function will be subject to C++ name mangling.

***Solution (revisited):***

If the native method is static, both implementation and declaration must have a second argument of type 'jclass', otherwise, both must have a 'jobject' second argument.

Comment: If the function declaration is generated by javah it's probably the correct one, so it would be better to change the definition to match the declaration (not the other way round)

Comment: @user2543253 jni documentation dictates using jobject. However, either case works, as jclass is a subclass of jobject.

Comment: for static methods it's `jclass`, and while it may "work" it makes the code less clear.

Comment: I didn't know! can you provide a link?? his 'test' function is not static tough.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#native_method_arguments How do you know the OP's method isn't static?

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer accordingly. Neither the definition nor the declaration have defined 'test' as static.

Comment: @DUDUDU you should accept EHH's answer. And we would like to know if your Java method is static ;-) (I'm guessing "yes" because the header file looks javah generated)